# Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, web-scraping

Running selenium scrape on `Heroku`. It runs but after every 6-7 seconds it crashes with this error

> 2021-06-24T15:33:07.835601+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot
> timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of
> launch 2021-06-24T15:33:07.884148+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping
> process with SIGKILL 2021-06-24T15:33:08.022511+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
> Process exited with status 137 2021-06-24T15:33:08.119687+00:00
> heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import requests
from PIL import Image




GOOGLE_CHROME_PATH = '/app/.apt/usr/bin/google_chrome'
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = '/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver'
PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 13978))
options1 = Options()
options1.binary_location = os.environ.get('$GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN')
options1.add_argument("--headless")
options1.add_argument("--example-flag")
options1.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options1.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=str(os.environ.get('CHROMEDRIVER_PATH')),options=options1)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://tryshowtime.com/c/spotlights')
print("On the page")
time.sleep(6)
i = 0
old_rest = set()
while True:
    try:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,3225)", "")
        time.sleep(12)
        images = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="relative"]//img')
        ans = set(images) - set(old_rest)  # Remove old elements

        for image in ans:
            i += 1
            link = image.get_attribute('src')
            print(f"got {i}th" + "link")
            img_f = requests.get(link, stream=True)
            with open(f'Image_{i}.jpg', 'wb') as f:
                f.write(img_f.content)
            img = Image.open(f'Image_{i}.jpg')
            if img.mode != 'RGB':
                img = img.convert('RGB')
            img_final = img.resize((1024,1024))
            img_final.save(f'Image_{i}.jpg')
            print("Image saved successfully")

        old_rest = images
    except:
        pass
```

Looks like I am not setting the `port` right? The same used to run fine for another scraper on Heroku, but that scraper only ran on command not continuously. Can someone guide as to what might be the issue?

**INFO** :-This probably won't work on Heroku because it exceeds the `dyno's` memory (512 MB)?

Comment: Show your proc file, are you using a web Dyno?

Comment: @BeppeC This solved. I think changing it to `worker` like you say..was needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `web` in my `Procfile`. I changed it to `worker` and it worked.